# Whitelist rejection errors in PhoneGap 3.4

Tags: ios, cordova, sencha-touch

(I've searched for this extensively on Stack Overflow+Google but can't seem to find any solution; most stuff is looking at earlier PhoneGap versions)

I keep getting whitelist rejection errors on Xcode with my Sencha Touch 2.3 / PhoneGap 3.4 app:

```
2014-04-23 00:46:25.978 HelloWorld[95912:60b] ERROR whitelist rejection: url='http://www.bodbot.com/Scripts/script.php?_dc=1398239185976'
2014-04-23 00:48:20.555 HelloWorld[95912:4003] ERROR whitelist rejection: url='http://www.bodbot.com/Scripts/script2.php?_dc=1398239300554'
```

Following the instructions of the [PhoneGap Whitelist Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide) I've manually added `<access origin="http://bodbot.com" />` and `<access origin="https://bodbot.com" />` to every instance of config.xml in the project directory:

```
/config.xml 
/phonegap/www/config.xml 
/phonegap/platforms/ios/HelloWorld/config.xml 
/phonegap/platforms/ios/www/config.xml
```

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the app multiple times on both the emulator and my phone as well. Nothing seems to remove the whitelist rejection errors. Any help/direction pointing here would be awesomesauce.

Comment: Have you tried just one entry of `<access origin="*.bodbot.com" />`? I don't believe that these settings stack, meaning which ever is last is the one that will be set.

Comment: Wow, alright, that worked. I feel kinda dumb now given how simple that was. Certainly feel free to make that a full post and I'll give you the check mark :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the config.xml property `<access origin="" />` is not stackable. Meaning if you assign more than one, only the last value will be assigned.

In your case that would mean only the `https://` requests would be allowed.

Try using only `<access origin="*.bodbot.com" />`

Answer (score 0):

> The following examples demonstrate whitelist syntax:
>
> Access to google.com:
>
> Access to the secure google.com
>   (https://):
>
> Access to the subdomain
>   maps.google.com:
>
> Access to all the
>   subdomains on google.com, for example mail.google.com and
>   docs.google.com:
>
> Access to all domains, for
>   example, google.com and developer.mozilla.org: